# How to prove the identity $\frac{1}{\sin(z)} = \cot(z) + \tan(\frac{z}{2})$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{1}{\sin(z)} = \cot (z) + \tan (\tfrac{z}{2})$$

I did this:

**First attempt**: $$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sin (z)} = \frac{\cos (z)}{\sin (z)} + \frac{\sin (\frac{z}{2})}{ \cos (\frac{z}{2})} = \frac{\cos (z) }{\sin (z)} + \frac{2\sin(\frac{z}{4})\cos(\frac{z}{4})}{\cos^{2}(\frac{z}{4})-\sin^{2}(\frac{z}{4})}} = $$
$$\frac{\cos (z)(\cos^{2}(\frac{z}{4})-\sin^{2}(\frac{z}{4}))+2\sin z \sin(\frac{z}{4})\cos(\frac{z}{4})}{\sin (z)(\cos^{2}(\frac{z}{4})-\sin^{2}(\frac{z}{4}))}$$

Stuck.

**Second attempt**:

$$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sin z} = \left(\frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})\right)^{-1} = 2i\left(\frac{1}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}\right)}$$

Stuck.

Does anybody see a way to continue?

Comment: For your first strategy: You want to compare arguments $z$ and $z/2$, so you should halve $z$ with the formula, not $z/2$. For your second strategy: This is fine, now replace the right side also by exponentials and clear denominators. People post shorter solutions, but you should reflect that both of your ideas actually work fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$ \frac{\cos (z)}{\sin (z)} + \frac{\sin (\frac{z}{2})}{ \cos (\frac{z}{2})} =\frac{\cos (z)\cos (\frac{z}{2})+ \sin(z)\sin (\frac{z}{2}) }{\sin (z)\cos (\frac{z}{2})}  =\frac{\cos (z-\frac{z}{2})}{\sin (z)\cos (\frac{z}{2})}$$

Comment: Rather elegant :-)

Comment: $\displaystyle{ \frac{cos(-\frac{z}{2})}{sin(z) cos(\frac{z}{2}} = \frac{cos(\frac{z}{2})}{sin(z)cos(\frac{z}{2}} = \frac{1}{sin(z)} }$

Answer (score 3):

Let $w = \frac{z}{2}$. Then
$$
\cot(2w) + \tan(w) = \frac{\cos^2(w)-\sin^2(w)}{2 \sin(w) \cos(w)} + \frac{\sin(w)}{\cos(w)} = \frac{1}{\cos(w)} \left( \frac{\cos^2(w)-\sin^2(w) + 2 \sin^2(w)}{2 \sin(w)} \right)
$$
The numerator becomes 1, and we arrive at the result $\frac{1}{2 \sin(w) \cos(w)} = \frac{1}{\cos(2w)} = \frac{1}{\cos(z)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Start out with
$$
\frac{1-\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}=\frac{2\sin^2(\tfrac{z}{2})}{2\sin(\tfrac{z}{2})\cos(\tfrac{z}{2})}=\tan(\tfrac{z}{2})\tag{1}
$$
and add $\cot(z)$ to both sides:
$$
\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\cot(z)+\tan(\tfrac{z}{2})\tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'll go backwards; I hope you don't mind.

$$\begin{align*}\cot\,z+\tan\frac{z}{2}&=\frac{\cos\,z}{\sin\,z}+\frac{\sin\,z}{1+\cos\,z}\\&=\frac{\sin^2 z+(1+\cos\,z)\cos\,z}{(1+\cos\,z)\sin\,z}\\&=\frac{\cos^2 z+\sin^2 z+\cos\,z}{(1+\cos\,z)\sin\,z}\\&=\frac{1+\cos\,z}{(1+\cos\,z)\sin\,z}\\&=\csc\,z\end{align*}$$